# Deserialize a list of serialized json strings

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, json.net

The `result` object is a list of string. Each string in this list is a serialised JSON object.

This is the serialised "result" :

```
["{\"Id\":\"91e02276\",\"Message\":\"Hi There\"}","{\"Id\":\"91e02277\",\"Message\":\"Hi again\"}"]
```

Deserializing one works correctly:

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DTO>(result[0]);
```

How do I get to deserialize the full result list? This does not work:

```
var y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DTO>>(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.ToArray()));
```

Comment: Please provide the data.

Comment: ["{\"Id\":\"91e02276\",\"Message\":\"Hi There\"}","{\"Id\":\"91e02277\",\"Message\":\"Hi again\"}"]

Comment: @PeterPitLock is that `result`? You should edit the question and put it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Deserialize each string in result using Linq. For example, assuming your Dto to be defined as following.

```
public class Dto
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Message{get;set;}
}
```

You can deserialize as,

```
var result = new []{"{\"Id\":\"91e02276\",\"Message\":\"Hi There\"}","{\"Id\":\"91e02277\",\"Message\":\"Hi again\"}"};
var dtos = result.Select(x=> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dto>(x));
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If each item in `result` is a seralized `DTO`, just iterate through `result` and deserialize each item one at a time.

```
var dtoList = new List<DTO>();
foreach (var json in result)
{
   dtoList.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DTO>(json));
}
```

Comment: Or, via LINQ, `var dtoList = result.Select(json => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DTO>(json)).ToList();`